# How to fix "teminated due to timeout" error in the problem Array Manipulation | Hackerrank?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying to solve the array manipulation problem on hackerrank, but it 
shows "terminated due to timeout" in some of the test cases. How can it 
be fixed?

Here's a link to the problem: 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem

Here's my piece of code trying to solve it.

```cpp
// Complete the arrayManipulation function below.
long arrayManipulation(int n, vector<vector<int>> queries) {
    ll* a=new ll[n];
    ll k;
    for(k=0;k<n;k++){
        a[k]=0;
    }
    ll i,j,b,c,s;
    long int m=-999999;
    for(i=0;i<queries.size();i++){
        b=queries[i][0]-1;
        c=queries[i][1]-1;
        s=queries[i][2];
        for(j=b;j<=c;j++){
            a[j]=a[j]+s;
            if(a[j]>m)
                m=a[j];
        }
    }
    delete [] a;

    return m;
}
```

This is one of the test cases which results in "terminated due to 
    timeout".

```
Input
10000000 100000
7253005 9867484 26205
933415 3777144 94765
4459151 9562860 92614
2789917 8588211 4461
4044644 5402538 67512
5713942 9159751 16533
9098636 9929072 64666
292166 3522306 31552
894426 9902580 83056
741032 5667470 18090
3359393 5436826 85573
6370240 8401950 79068
1996715 3345743 41927
205681 8652011 46490
210142 2696654 65379
4372756 6194007 79320
4301827 5510540 94307
2991558 7824132 2824
243063 3223110 97250{-truncated-}
<<Plz Download to view the full testcase>>

Expected Output
2490686975
```

Comment: It would appear that making a 10 million item array and making billions of writes into it is not going to produce an answer in time. Is there perhaps some way to do less work?

Comment: You could probe the intervals for results directly, the maximum is only going to occur at the start or end of one of them, so you have 200000 points to check. With a naïve approach, checking one point requires you to walk the whole table (point inside interval? -> add value). So overall you need about 20 000 000 000 steps, still not good enough.

Comment: I think the successful approach is going to require building a list of non-overlapping ranges with their respective values. Build the list gradually from the input ranges by taking one range from the input, finding what ranges in the list it intersects with and adding its value to them.

Comment: I'm not going to give you detailed code, this exercise is supposed to evaluate you after all...

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Come up with a faster algorithm.

This is not an easy problem (marked 'hard' on Hackerrank, though it's actually 'medium' IMHO), hence don't expect that a literal implementation of the algorithm as described will solve it. That algorithm takes *O(nm)* time, but there is a simple method that takes only *O(n+m)* time. I coded it up on Hackerrank in 10 lines of code: it passed all test cases at first attempt.

I don't give you the solution here, as you should work that out yourself, but, apart from the initialization, there is just one pass over the *m* queries, taking *O(1)* amount of work for each followed by one pass over the *n* elements, again taking *O(1)* work for each. Hint: think differentiated.